# Python different lists give back same result

Tags: python, list, class

So I have a class that contains different classes

```
class MergedFile:
    objs = []
    def __init__(self, path1, path2, path3 ,path4):
        self.objs.append(Obj(path1))
        self.objs.append(Obj(path2))
        self.objs.append(Obj(path3))
        self.objs.append(Obj(path4))
        for obj in self.objs:
            print(obj.vertices)
```

So Obj is a class that reads a info from a file and stores it in an array

```
class Obj:
    path = ""
    vertices = []
    def __init__(self, path):
        if(not os.path.exists(path)): 
            return
        self.path = path
        self.getVertices()
        print(self.vertices)
```

when I print the list in the constructor of each individual object it gives me different lists as it should be. But when I do this:

```
for obj in self.objs:
    print(obj.vertices)
```

in the constructor of the `MergedFile` class it prints the same list of the last object in the list 4 times. Am I missing something really obvious here? Because it doesn't really makes sense to me.

Comment: Can't reproduce because not a [mre].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a mutable list, `vertices`, as a class attribute in your `Obj` class.  This list is shared across all instances of the `Obj`.  You need to move it to with in the `__init__`.  You should really move `path` as well just for cleaner code (in this case, just remove it from the class attributes).

Lastly, your `__init__` should never `return` anything.  If you want to check for the path's existence, you should `raise`.  Then handle the error elsewhere if needed.

```
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, path):
        if(not os.path.exists(path)): 
            raise FileNotFoundError
        self.vertices = []
        self.path = path
        self.getVertices()
        print(self.vertices)
```

You have the same issue with `objs` in your `MergedFiles` class.  If you only have one instance of `MergedFiles` it is ok, but more than one instance will share that list.